# Classic ADO SQLSetEnvAttr Return Code

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odbc, ado

I am creating classic ADO connection pooling for ODBC as described on this KB article

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/237844

However, when executing the SQLSetEnvAttr function I receive a large number as a return value. 147082878 to be exact.

What is the meaning of this number? According to the KB article any number other than 0 is an error but this extremely large number doesn't correspond to any ODBC error constant.

Thank you.

EDIT: Code Included:

```
Dim rc As Long
Const SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING = 201
Const SQL_CP_ONE_PER_DRIVER = 1
Const SQL_IS_INTEGER = -6
Const SQL_CP_OFF = 0

#If Win32 Then
Private Declare Function SQLSetEnvAttr Lib "odbc32.dll" (ByVal EnvironmentHandle As Long, _
                                                        ByVal EnvAttribute As Long, _
                                                        ByVal ValuePtr As Long, _
                                                        ByVal StringLength As Long) As Integer
#End If

''' <summary>
''' 
''' Call connection pool for new connections (ODBC)
''' 
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub ConnectionPool()

    Try
        rc = SQLSetEnvAttr(0&, _
                           SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING, _
                           SQL_CP_ONE_PER_DRIVER, _
                           SQL_IS_INTEGER)
        If rc <> 0 Then
#If DEBUG Then
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
#End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
#If DEBUG Then
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
#End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: You tagged both VB.Net and VB6. Which language are you actually using? (Edit your question to remove the invalid tag.) Also, is there a reason you cannot use an OLE DB driver? Finally, you should edit your post to include code that reproduces the error.

Comment: Hi, sorry it is a VB6 application ported to VB.net through the automatic conversion tool so it's a ton of legacy code. The code was developed against {Microsoft ODBC for Oracle} driver and there is an "Attempted to Access Protected or Read Only Memory" error when trying the Oracle client drivers after a large number of connections so we reverted to the legacy driver until such time we can redevelop in ADO.NET or ODP.NET. I will add code to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have only used ODBC from the C API (not from ADO) so far.

Normally all `SQL...` ODBC functions are passed a handle as the first parameter, but in case of connection pooling `SQLSetEnvAttr` is passed a `NULL` handle. (It is important that you do this before the environment handle is allocated as stated in the kb article.)

If the return value indicates failure, you can run `SQLGetDiagRec` (or `SQLGetDiagField`) to get the error details.

I do not know if the `SQLGetDiag...` functions work on a `NULL` handle, but that is what I would try first.